# Error 404 from Google Search API

Tags: c#, google-search-api

I'm getting a 404 error from the code below. I'm running Visual C# Express 2010. The query portion of the string is:

> `q%3dAction%2bMotivation%2c%2bInc.%2bSouth%2bSan%2bFrancisco%2b%26alt%3djson%26start%3d0%26num%3d10"`

```
string searchString =       
    "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1%3fkey%3d{APIkey}%26cx%3d{cxkey}%26q%3dAction%2bMotivation%2c%2bInc.%2bSouth%2bSan%2bFrancisco%2b%26alt%3djson%26start%3d0%26num%3d10";
WebRequest myRequest = WebRequest.Create(searchString);
HttpWebResponse myResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse();
```

Comment: Why are you escaping the `&` and `=` parts? And why is there no `?`? I'd expect something like `https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=...&cx=...&q=Action%2bMotivation%2c` etc. (Where the `...` is filled in with your actual keys of course)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're escaping far too much. You should only escape the query value - not the key/value pair separators. So the URL should be something like:

```
string url = string.Format(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key={0}&cx={1}&q={2}",
    HttpUtility.UrlEncode(apiKey),
    HttpUtility.UrlEncode(cxKey),
    HttpUtility.UrlEncode(query));
```

(Where `query` is the *original* query, e.g. "Action Motivation Inc." (I haven't checked what the escape sequences you're using actually represent.)

Comment: Thanks, Jon, that was the problem.